# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("https://github.com/KeithGalli/pandas/blob/master/pokemon_data.csv")
print (df)
```

it works fine, then when i try to manipulate on the file it just give me the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-eb4b6e6a1e41> in <module>()
----> 1 print (df.head)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Comment: `pd.read_html` returns a list of dataframes, not a dataframe. Use `df[0].head()` to see the first table.

Answer (score 1):

[`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) tries reads tables from an HTML file, but you're trying to read a CSV file, so you want to use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead:

Also, the URL you're using is invalid. You want to the [actual URL](https://github.com/KeithGalli/pandas/blob/master/pokemon_data.csv) to the raw CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/KeithGalli/pandas/blob/master/pokemon_data.csv")
print (df)
```

Comment: That URL should probably be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KeithGalli/pandas/master/pokemon_data.csv`. The other URL will give them an HTML preview of the CSV file.

Comment: Good point, that's probably what the OP got wrong in the first place.

Comment: thank you so much, Nick, it seems to be working, i actually had to play with it before and i finaly decided to try with html, but thanks to you, it seems to be working